# Two persons independently using one MacBook Pro

Tags: sharing, multitasking

Is it possible for such a setup as the following: Hooking *one* MacBook Pro up with two separate monitors, two separate mice, and two separate keyboards, allowing two different persons to work independently on their monitors, sharing the computer's performance?

Perhaps this is a strange request, but it would actually be useful for me in certain situations. With enough adapters, simply *connecting* the computer to the necessary monitors, mice, and keyboards should be possible; however, the interesting part is how to allow to share the computer's performance and sending independent data to the two monitors.

Comment: I've never heard of anyone being able to do this.  What research have you done so far and what have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

no, in fact you cannot SIMULTANEOUSLY use a system with two separate users logged in simultaneously on two different monitors.

several other options may allow something similar:
1 user logged in on the display.
2nd user logged in via SSH to terminal as any available user..

However this won't allow the computer to drive 2 displays - the 2nd user would be able to do terminal commands only, and could in fact overide any actions done by the first user (depending on permissions, user account, etc)...

Answer (score 0):

There is precedent for this type of thing in the client/server world, with multiple users logging into a server from their own clients.

The problem is that there is no adapter (that I am aware of) to allow a second physically connected set of hardware to use a different user account than the one in use by the first set of hardware. Without such an adapter, you're just going to be fighting over the same mouse cursor and keyboard inputs.

With another device available, you may be able to use that device to remotely connect to the MacBook Pro with a different user account and have them operating simultaneously.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately it is not possible to have 2 separate users on the same machine both using their own mouse/keyboard/monitor.

Comment: Could you perhaps explain why?

Comment: [Here's a post why 2 cursors doesn't work](http://superuser.com/questions/649325/two-mice-two-pointers-one-mac)

Comment: The linked question envisions using two mice simultaneously by the same person. This question is about two people using two mice independently, presumably with separate user accounts. The question, therefore, would be can you have two users logged into macOS and each using their own account, simultaneously?